# How to visualize second order differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, visualization

As we now we can use `StreamPlot` to visualize first-order differential equations like:`y'[x]==1+x-y`

```
StreamPlot[{1, 1 + x - y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Axes -> True, 
 Frame -> False]
```

[image]

But how about second-order differential equations? Such as `y''[x]+2y'[x]+3y==0`?Can we visualize it?

Comment: Please see the above link. It shows how to do it for second order ODE.

Comment: @Nasser It's hard to imagine this topic with such a title. I searched for a long time and didn't find it.

Comment: I agree on the title, but I just remembered it myself and searched for it.

Comment: @Nasser Are you saying you have memorized the title you quoted?

Comment: No, I meant  I remembered similar question was asked before, so was able to find it by googling. I have good memory :)

Comment: If we make `y'=x`, then we can convert it into `{y',x'}={{1,0},{-2,-3}}.{x,y}`, then we can use `StreamPlot`